# Terrible graphics performance with Intel graphics on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: graphics, 13.10, intel-graphics

Graphics performance is now terrible (videos play at ~1 fps, opening Dash is extremely slow etc) on my Dell Latitude E4300 after upgrading to 13.10 (13.04 was fine). The graphics adapter is listed as: " Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (version 7)".

Any ideas on where to look for the problem?

Comment: I'm glad to see you have fixed your problem but please don't post the answer as a comment post it as an Answer. You can then accept the answer.  This helps other users with a similar problem find it also provides an opportunity for you to earn some reputation.

Comment: @Warren I couldn't due to askubuntu rules (8 hour lockout from asking to answering own question), have moved it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else that runs into this problem, it doesn't appear to have anything to do with the graphics driver, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-desktop-privileges/+bug/1240336.

To fix, run:
sudo pam-auth-update --force

and reboot. This fixes numerous other problems (unable to mount flash drives, no sound, can't run software updater).